# Facebook Shared Link - Scrape blog page right after published

Tags: c#, facebook, umbraco

I'm developing a blog website (using Umbraco) where it also can share its blog page to Facebook automatically after the page has been published. I have created a Facebook app and used Facebook SDK for .NET in order to that and it works but one small problem is that when the link is shared for the first time, it looks ugly. No image, no title and no description, just url. I have to publish the second time to get the proper link. Heres what I've done so far:-

- Programmatically use the scrape API using Facebook SDK for .NET. I even tried to loop through the scrape API 10x to test if it work but doesn't.
- Supply the necessary Open Graph Tag in the header of the shared page.

  - og:title
  - og:description
  - og:image
  - og:image:width
  - og:image:height
  - og:type
  - og:fb_id
  - og:site_name

I'm using Umbraco ContentService Events to invoke the Facebook API functions:-

```
public class PublishEventHandler : ApplicationEventHandler
{

   protected override void ApplicationStarted(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
   {
      ContentService.Published += ContentServicePublished;
   }

   private void ContentServicePublished(IPublishingStrategy sender, PublishEventArgs<IContent> args)
   {

        foreach (var node in args.PublishedEntities)
        {

            foreach (var item in node.Properties)
            {
                //check property alias and its value
                if (item.Alias == "autoPost" && (int)item.Value == 1)
                {

                  var fbClient = new FacebookAuthClient();
                  var pageToken = fbClient.GetPageToken();
                  var url = umbraco.library.NiceUrlWithDomain(node.Id);

                  fbClient.ScrapePage(url, pageToken);
                  fbClient.SharePostOnPage(url, pageToken);

                 }
             }
          }
     }
 }
```

Scrape API function:-

```
 public void ScrapePage(string url, string pageToken)
 {
    var scrapeResult = new FacebookClient(pageToken)
    {
            Version = "v2.9"
    };

    var response = scrapeResult.Post(new { id = url, scrape = "true" });

    LogHelper.Info(this.GetType(), "|SCRAPE| " + response.ToString());
 }
```

Share API function:-

```
  public void SharePostOnPage(string url, string pageToken)
  {

     if (pageToken != null)
     {
         var result = new FacebookClient(pageToken)
         {
                Version = "v2.9"
         };
         var response = result.Post("/" + AuthConfig.facebookPageId + "/feed", new { link = url, scrape = "true" });

         LogHelper.Info(this.GetType(), "|SHARE| " + response.ToString());
        }
    }
```

One more thing I want to add is when I checked the response for the scrape in the log. I only get the id and url but when I used the Graph API Explorer in https://developers.facebook.com I got the whole information of the page (id,url,title,description,etc..) and yes I've been Googling and researching for a week now for this problem before deciding to post this.

Comment: What _result_ do you get from automatically scraping? What does the debug tool say? As long as there are errors, I don’t think it updates/creates any OG data for such a URL.

Comment: @CBroe I did not received any warnings from the debug tool since I already fixed them all few days ago but still the problem occurs

Comment: @CBroe if you're wondering what were my warnings before this is it complains about my image exceeded the maximum allowed sized of 8Mb and my server was too slow to respond.

Comment: Anyone? Help please